# Como exibir dados de um usuário em uma página através do ID?

Tags: php

estou desenvolvendo um site onde o administrador pode visualizar os dados cadastrais de todos os usuários que estão cadastrados no sistema, e esses dados são exibidos em uma tabela. 
A tabela só exibe alguns dados (id, nome e email) e eu quero fazer um link onde o administrador pode clicar para ver as informações completas do usuário selecionado. Por exemplo, se ele clicar no link "ver mais" do usuário com ID 1, a tela exibe todos os dados dele (id, nome, rg, cpf, email, data de nascimento).

Meu código por enquanto é esse:

```
<?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM adms";
    $con = mysqli_query($con, $consulta) or die (mysqli_error);
?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="25px;">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td></td>           
    </tr>
    <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dado['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['email'] ?></td>
            <td><a href="adm_vermaisAdm.php?id='$dado[id]'">Ver mais</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

A tabela fica assim:

[image: Tabela que mostra dados de todos os administradores cadastrados]

Minhas principais dúvidas são:

1) A linha `<a href="adm_vermaisAdm.php?id='$dado[id]'">Ver mais</a>` está declarada do jeito certo? Estou em dúvida por causa do $dado[id], não sei se vai funcionar desse jeito

2) Para criar a página de exibição dos dados, o nome dela seria adm_vermaisAdm.php?id='$dado[id]' ?

3) Para exibir esses dados, como eu faço pra pegar o ID da URL?

Desde já agradeço a todos que responderem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa! tudo bom?
Acho que consigo lhe ajudar. Na ordem das dúvidas:

**Primeira dúvida**

A forma como está escrito não vai funcionar. Lembre-se que a tag `<a>` é HTML e que para interpolar dados php em sua declaração, você deve novamente abrir a tag do php. Segue exemplo:

```
<a href="adm_vermaisAdm.php?id='<?php echo $dado['id']?>'">Ver mais</a>
```

Isso já irá garantir que a sua âncora esteja apontando para a página "adm_vermaisAdm.php", passando na url o parâmetro id, com valor igual ao que está armazenado na váriavel $dado['id'].

**Segunda dúvida**

A resposta é não!
A página (arquivo php) que você está apontando na âncora é a "adm_vermaisAdm.php" e é assim que o arquivo deve ser nomeado.

```
adm_vermaisAdm.php
```

**Terceira dúvida**

Para pegar o id que veio pela sua URL, tu podes fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Assim você já terá em mãos o id para realizar a consulta no e exibir todos os dados referentes ao mesmo.

Espero ter ajudado :D!

Comment: Muito obrigada! Consegui exibir os dados sem problemas :)